# ¿Cómo hacer un preloader con una imagen?

Tags: html, css, spinner

quisiera crear un preloader con una imagen que tengo un mis recursos, y quisiera saber la forma de hacerlo, e visto varios per con spinners u otros elementos, pero no con una imagen personalizada, ayuda.

Comment: Mira [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada. ¿En cuanto a lo de una imagen como spinner te refieres añadir animaciones css a la imagen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo de lo que uso yo, para que solo le insertes la imagen que vos queres.

```js
$(document).on("ready",function(){
            $(window).on('load', function(){
                $('#pageloader-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
            });
        });
```

```css
 #pageloader-overlay {
            opacity: 0;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 9998;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
            transition: opacity 0.2s linear; 
        }

        #pageloader-overlay.visible {
            opacity: 1; 
        }

        #pageloader-overlay.hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0px;
            width: 0px;
            z-index: -10000; 
        }

        #pageloader-overlay .loader-wrapper-outer {
            background-color: transparent;
            z-index: 9999;
            margin: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: table;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle; 
        }

        #pageloader-overlay .loader-wrapper-inner {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle; 
        }
```

```html
<div id="pageloader-overlay" class="visible incoming">
        <div class="loader-wrapper-outer">
            <div class="loader-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="text-center new-loading-modal">
                    <!--INSERTAR LA IMAGEN ACÁ!-->
                    <img src="https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo es eso lo que buscaba